# PDF conversion with Ghostscript breaks the fonts

Tags: pdf, fonts, ghostscript

I'm trying to merge pdfs together with Ghostscript, but having font problems. Below screenshot - left is input, right is output. "Standard" latin parts are correct, non-standard wrong (CID?), although they are using the same font.

[image: screenshot]

This is script output (extra line breaks and numbers added by me for clarity):

```
$ gs -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=out.pdf in.pdf
GPL Ghostscript 9.26 (2018-11-20)
Copyright (C) 2018 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.
Processing pages 1 through 1.
Page 1
-- 1
Can't find (or can't open) font file /usr/share/ghostscript/9.26/Resource/Font/TimesNewRomanPSMT.
Can't find (or can't open) font file TimesNewRomanPSMT.
Can't find (or can't open) font file /usr/share/ghostscript/9.26/Resource/Font/TimesNewRomanPSMT.
Can't find (or can't open) font file TimesNewRomanPSMT.
Querying operating system for font files...
Can't find (or can't open) font file /usr/share/ghostscript/9.26/Resource/Font/TimesNewRomanPSMT.
Can't find (or can't open) font file TimesNewRomanPSMT.
Didn't find this font on the system!
Substituting font Times-Roman for TimesNewRomanPSMT.
Loading NimbusRoman-Regular font from /usr/share/ghostscript/9.26/Resource/Font/NimbusRoman-Regular... 5046332 3572454 3115872 1726420 4 done.

-- 2
Can't find CID font "TimesNewRoman".
Attempting to substitute CID font /Adobe-Identity for /TimesNewRoman, see doc/Use.htm#CIDFontSubstitution.
The substitute CID font "Adobe-Identity" is not provided either. attempting to use fallback CIDFont.See doc/Use.htm#CIDFontSubstitution.
Loading a TT font from /usr/share/ghostscript/9.26/Resource/CIDFSubst/DroidSansFallback.ttf to emulate a CID font Adobe-Identity ... Done.

-- 3
Can't find (or can't open) font file /usr/share/ghostscript/9.26/Resource/Font/TimesNewRomanPS-ItalicMT.
Can't find (or can't open) font file TimesNewRomanPS-ItalicMT.
Can't find (or can't open) font file /usr/share/ghostscript/9.26/Resource/Font/TimesNewRomanPS-ItalicMT.
Can't find (or can't open) font file TimesNewRomanPS-ItalicMT.
Didn't find this font on the system!
Substituting font Times-Italic for TimesNewRomanPS-ItalicMT.
Loading NimbusRoman-Italic font from /usr/share/ghostscript/9.26/Resource/Font/NimbusRoman-Italic... 9238300 7844767 3270416 1870892 4 done.

-- 4
Can't find CID font "TimesNewRoman".
Attempting to substitute CID font /Adobe-Identity for /TimesNewRoman, see doc/Use.htm#CIDFontSubstitution.
Can't find (or can't open) font file /usr/share/ghostscript/9.26/Resource/Font/TimesNewRomanPS-BoldMT.
Can't find (or can't open) font file TimesNewRomanPS-BoldMT.
Can't find (or can't open) font file /usr/share/ghostscript/9.26/Resource/Font/TimesNewRomanPS-BoldMT.
Can't find (or can't open) font file TimesNewRomanPS-BoldMT.
Didn't find this font on the system!
Substituting font Times-Bold for TimesNewRomanPS-BoldMT.
Loading NimbusRoman-Bold font from /usr/share/ghostscript/9.26/Resource/Font/NimbusRoman-Bold... 9486596 8090953 3465360 2062449 4 done.

-- 5
Can't find CID font "TimesNewRoman".
Attempting to substitute CID font /Adobe-Identity for /TimesNewRoman, see doc/Use.htm#CIDFontSubstitution.
Can't find (or can't open) font file /usr/share/ghostscript/9.26/Resource/Font/Arial-BoldMT.
Can't find (or can't open) font file Arial-BoldMT.
Can't find (or can't open) font file /usr/share/ghostscript/9.26/Resource/Font/Arial-BoldMT.
Can't find (or can't open) font file Arial-BoldMT.
Didn't find this font on the system!
Substituting font Helvetica-Bold for Arial-BoldMT.
Loading NimbusSans-Bold font from /usr/share/ghostscript/9.26/Resource/Font/NimbusSans-Bold... 9735428 8335065 3720904 2297241 4 done.

-- 6
Can't find CID font "Arial".
Attempting to substitute CID font /Adobe-Identity for /Arial, see doc/Use.htm#CIDFontSubstitution.
Can't find CID font "Arial".
Attempting to substitute CID font /Adobe-Identity for /Arial, see doc/Use.htm#CIDFontSubstitution.
```

Having a bit difficulties to understand what GS is trying to tell me. What exactly is CID font? More importantly, how do I fix this? Another option - how to copy embedded fonts from original pdf to new one with GS?

Comment: You are using a seriously ancient version of Ghostscript, try using something more modern, the current version is 10.02.. If you continue to have problems then you can open a bug report, don't forget to attach the specimen files. A CIDFont is a kind of font, clearly at least one of your files uses a font arranged as a CIDFont and does not include it. CIDFonts **must** be embedded in PDF files for correct results. You can probably work around it by adding the Windows TrueType fonts as CIDFonts to the Ghostscript font map, if you are lucky. But I'd try a version less than 5 years old first.

Comment: True about version thing, will do :). Not sure about "not embedded" theory, because original file displays correctly.

Comment: Just because a PDF consumer can substitute a font successfully doesn't mean the font is embedded, or that another consumer will be able to do the same, since it will almost certainly use a different substitute.

Comment: Sadly I have Ubuntu 18 and this is the latest GS available. Any other ideas? Can you tell what exactly is problem with those fonts, why "latin" is correct and "non-latin" not although they use the same font?

Comment: as pointed out those fonts aren't installed in your system and ghostscript can't handle a suitable substitution. The proper solution would be to provide an explicit font mapping that will resolve each of those unresolved font with something existing on the system when instructing ghostscript. Anyway as a last resort you may try to give `pdftk` a chance.. it may succeed (or not). Try doing something like `pdftk file1.pdf file2.pdf cat output merged.pdf
`

Comment: Almost certainly 'latin' is using a regular font, while 'non-latin' is using a CIDFont. Fontsuse character codes and they are a single byte, CIDFonts uses Character IDs which are defined by using a CMap and can have an arbitrary number of bytes. I have seen CMaps defining CIDs using up to 5 bytes. Substituting a font with another font will often work, and I would suspect that the first missing font, TimesNewRomanPSMT, which is substituted with NumbusRoman-Regular and is a regular font works. Doing the same with a CIDFont doesn't,

Comment: You can, as Diego D said while I was writing, add an explicit font mapping for the fonts and an explicit CIDFont mapping for the CIDFonts. You **might** be able to use the Windows TrueType fotns as substitute CIDFonts if you are lucky, as I said initially. You would need to modify Resource/Init/cidfmap to include the TrueType font. See https://ghostscript.readthedocs.io/en/gs10.0.0/Use.html#explicit-cidfont-substitution Also you can always build GS from source, so you can get the latest GS on Ubuntu 18, it just isn't packaged.

Comment: @KenS Got it working, thanks for your help. Still not sure why this problem appeared suddenly for Lithuanian characters - it has worked for years and CID fonts is mainly Asian thing, no?

Comment: No CIDFonts are for any script. It is true that Eastern languages tend to require CIDFonts, since the scripts often have > 256 characters, but you can use CIDFonts for any language. If you want (for example) to use UTF16 character codes, then you need a CIDFont. More and more PDF producers are using CIDFonts (and not embedding them! Which they should do) so this sort of problem is becoming more common. Preuismably you simply haven't seen a PDF file from that particular PDF producer (or that version of it) before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Installed `ttf-mscorefonts-installer`, clear font cache just in case (dunno if necessary)

```
apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
fc-cache -f -v
```

1.1) Location of installed fonts was in my case `/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts`

2. Added CID font to TTF mappings into `cidfmap`, in my case in folder `/var/lib/ghostscript/fonts/`:

```
/TimesNewRoman << /FileType /TrueType /Path (/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/times.ttf) /SubfontID 0 /CSI [(Identity) 0] >> ;
/TimesNewRoman,Bold << /FileType /TrueType /Path (/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/timesbd.ttf) /SubfontID 0 /CSI [(Identity) 0] >> ;
/TimesNewRoman,Italic << /FileType /TrueType /Path (/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/timesi.ttf) /SubfontID 0 /CSI [(Identity) 0] >> ;
/TimesNewRoman,Bold,Italic << /FileType /TrueType /Path (/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/timesbi.ttf) /SubfontID 0 /CSI [(Identity) 0] >> ;
/Arial << /FileType /TrueType /Path (/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/arial.ttf) /SubfontID 0 /CSI [(Identity) 0] >> ;
/Arial,Bold << /FileType /TrueType /Path (/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/arialbd.ttf) /SubfontID 0 /CSI [(Identity) 0] >> ;
/Arial,Italic << /FileType /TrueType /Path (/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/ariali.ttf) /SubfontID 0 /CSI [(Identity) 0] >> ;
/Arial,Bold,Italic << /FileType /TrueType /Path (/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/arialbi.ttf) /SubfontID 0 /CSI [(Identity) 0] >> ;
```

NOTE Not sure if name for bold+italic ("/Arial,Bold,Italic") is correct, perhaps somebody can confirm this.

Comment: Unfortunately the naming of font styles is idiosyncratic, at best. there are no rules. You can get ArialBoldItalic, Arial-BoldItalic, Arial,BoldItalic, Arial,Bold-Italic etc etc. I've never seen Arial,Bold,Italic, but that doesn't mean it's not possible. PDF producers **should** embed CIDFonts, the spec says so, but they often don't. Worse than that, they often use an Identity-H CMap which means that the only way to get the expected result is to use the same font as the Producer did. Sometimes even the same version of the font :-( But I'm glad you were able to get it working